# ExternalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null with Skulpt runit() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, skulpt

I am getting an:

```
ExternalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null on line 2
```

in the console log from this code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <title>Python Coding Area</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
function outf(text) { 
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; 
} 
function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
            throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
    return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
}
function runit() { 
   var prog = document.getElementById("textbox").value; 
   var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe"); 
   mypre.innerHTML = ''; 
   Sk.pre = "output";
   Sk.configure({output:outf, read:builtinRead}); 
   (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'canvas';
   var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
       return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
   });
   myPromise.then(function(mod) {
       console.log('success');
   },
       function(err) {
       console.log(err.toString());
   });
} 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:Raleway !important;">
        <textarea id="textbox" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><br /> 
<button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button> 
</form> 
        <pre id="dynamicframe" ></pre> 
<div id="canvas"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

when I click the run button to run the python code with skulpt. Is there a problem with using skulpt in this context? I took some of the code from the skulpt website (skulpt.org) and changed it around a bit. Why am I getting the error and how can I stop it?

Comment: I suspect you have an initialization order problem. Are  you sure the DOM element with id "output" already exists when function out () is first called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'mypre' element does not exist in your webpage.

```
You should add a condition like this: 
var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 

if( mypre ) != null){
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; }
```

Comment: between which lines of javascript must I put this on?